# Use Google Analytics to figure out which events happen just before visitor exit

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-events, exit-pages

I am trying to track what a visitor does immediately prior to exiting our website. Specifically I have a number of events that are being logged and I would like to know which one, if any, happened immediately prior to leaving the site.

I can see that segments now have a 'sequence' option so I was wondering if there was a way to use this. I had a go at creating a segment that includes events of this type immediately followed by 'exits > 0' but this just seems to return every session that triggers one of these events. I assume it's looking for a values of exits > 0 rather than a change in the number of exits which is what I was hoping for.

Is there any way of analyzing events preceding exits like this?